# For any skew-symmetric $3×3$ matrix $A$, does there exist a symmetric $3×3$ matrix $B$ such that $AB+BA=O$

Tags: matrices

I got $2$ non zero matrices: $A$ and $B$.

$A^t=-A$ and $B^t=B$.

I try to understand if there is such matrix $B$ so the statment $AB + BA = O$ is true. I know that for $B=I$ it's not becuase $A$ will be $O$.

How can i find such matrix $B$ so it will be true? Both matrices are $3\times3$.

Thank you

Comment: To be clear, your question is : for any skew-symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix $A$, does there exist a symmetric  $3\times 3$ matrix $B$ such that $AB+BA=0$? Right?

Comment: B must be symetric, and then it is.

Comment: Hint: $[\begin{smallmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & \;0\end{smallmatrix}]
[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & \;0\\0 & -1\end{smallmatrix}] + 
[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & \;0\\0 & -1\end{smallmatrix}]
[\begin{smallmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & \;0\end{smallmatrix}] = ?$ (ref: [Pauli matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PauliMatrices.html))

Comment: I managed to find 2 3x3 matrices with your hits (just added middle row and column of zeroes). Thank you. But is there a rule for such matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$; we may assume (by a change of orthonormal basis) that the known matrix $A$ is $A=diag(0_{n-2k},U_1,\cdots,U_k)=diag(0_{n-2k},H_{2k})$ where $U_i=\begin{pmatrix}0&-a_i\\a_i&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $a_i\in \mathbb{R}^*$; note that $H$ is invertible skew-symmetric. If $u\in\ker(A)$, then $Bu\in\ker(A)$ and $\ker(A)$ is $B$-invariant. Since $B$ is symmetric, $(\ker(A))^{\perp}$ is also $B$-invariant. Then $B$ is in the form $diag(P_{n-2k},Q_{2k})$ where $P,Q$ are symmetric. Now $AB+BA=0$ can be rewritten $HQ+QH=0$ or $Q=-H^{-1}QH$; finally $spectrum(Q)$ is in the form $(q_1,-q_1,\cdots,q_k,-q_k)$.

Assume that $H$ is a generic invertible skew-symmetric matrix (in particular, its eigenvalues are distinct).

If $Hx=i\lambda x$ then $H(Qx)=-i\lambda Qx$, that is, $Q$ sends a complex eigenvector of $H$, associated to an eigenvalue $i\lambda$, to a vector in the eigenspace of $H$ associated to the conjugate eigenvalue $-i\lambda$. Thus $Q$ is in the form $Q=diag(V_1,\cdots,V_k)$ where $V_i$ is a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix such that $U_iV_i+V_iU_i=0$. After, it is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is nonzero, otherwise the statement is trivial. As $A$ is $3\times3$ and skew-symmetric, it is a [cross-product matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) $[ru]_\times$ for some $r\in\mathbb R$ and unit vector $u$. Extend $u$ to an ordered orthonormal basis $\{u,v,w\}$ so that $u\times v=w$. So, $(AB+BA)x=0$ for $x\in\{u,v,w\}$ if and only if
\begin{align}
u\times Bu &= -B(u\times u) = 0,\\
u\times Bv &= -B(u\times v) = -Bw,\tag{1}\\
u\times Bw &= -B(u\times w) =  Bv\tag{2}
\end{align}
Hence $Bu=tu$ for some $t\in\mathbb R$ and $Bw,\ Bv$ are linear combinations of $v$ and $w$. Let $Bv=av+bw$ and $Bw=cv+dw$. From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that $a=-d$ and $b=c$. In other words, $AB+BA=0$ if and only if $B$ is a linear operator such that $u\mapsto tu,\ v\mapsto av+bw,\ w\mapsto bv-aw$ for some $t,a,b\in\mathbb R$. If this is the case and $Q$ is the real orthogonal matrix whose columns are $u,v,w$, then
$$
A=Q\pmatrix{0\\ &0&-r\\ &r&0}Q^T,
\quad B=Q\pmatrix{t\\ &a&b\\ &b&-a}Q^T.
$$